# design a divide and conquer algorithm that takes O(n log n) determinations

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am given a set of balls and my ultimate goal is to find if at least half of the set of balls are the same color. I can only pick two balls each time and determine whether they are the same color or not. so how to design a divide and conquer algorithm that takes O(n log n) determinations to solve this problem? if there anybody has any idea on this problem, thank you so much!

Comment: I think this question needs to be edited to include a better explanation of the word "query". Specifically, what are the capabilities and limitations of a query?

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I have made a little change, hope it is easy to understand right now.

Comment: @JasonLee Do you have a fixed number of colors? Can they be ordered in some way? Or only compared for equality.

Comment: Unfortunately, they can only be compared for equality...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do it sort of backwards - if you don't know the answer in `n(log n)` comparisons, then less than half the balls are of the same color. Sort of merge-sort-group them...

```
r g r b r y r r  // worst case arrangement

rg rb ry rr      
    ↓            // 3 * (n / 4) comparisons
rr gb rrr y      
    ↓            // 3 * (n / 8) comparisons
rrrrr gby
```

Comment: Seems to be what I want, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can order the colors (e.g. you can just compute a hash for the color into integers which can be sorted; I cannot think of any data type that cannot be hashed). Then you can simply sort the balls by their color in `O(n log n)` time, and then sweep once through the sorted collection, and determine the runs of consecutive same-colored balls. Your answer is, whether the number of balls in the largest run is >= the number of balls.

**Edit**

The problem is actually O(n). Use a hash table with O(1) insertion for the n balls. Whenever you have it already in, increase the count on the element in the hash-table group, and keep track of the largest group count somewhere else.

You can even do an early exit whenever the max count reaches n/2, which should half the average run time on random sets.

**Edit2**

Sketch of an exemplary proof of O(n^2)

I strongly believe, that there is no O(n log n) solution when only equality comparisons are allowed. Look at the following example, which should yield true, there are exactly half As, the rest are all different:

First divide

```
n = 16
AAAAAAABCDEFGHIA
AAAAAAAB CDEFGHIA
AAAA AAAB CDEF GHIA
AA AA AA AB CD EF GH IA
```

now conquer. We need to find all groups in each conquer step, since each group could potentially be merged with another large group so that it is the majority of all groups.

In this example, int the left half A is clearly the winner, but we need one additional A in the right half. Since the right half does not have a knowledge of the left half in a divide and conquer setting, the right side also tries to find the largest group, ending with n/2 groups of size 1, before the final merge.

In the following notation I use a number before a letter to denote a found group of that size.

```
2A 2A 2A 1A1B 1C1D 1E1F 1G1H 1I1A  1+1+1+1 +1+1+1+1 =4+4 =8
4A       3A1B 1C1D1E1F  1G1H1I1A   1*1+2*1 +2*2+2*2 =3+8 =11
7A1B          1C1D1E1F1G1H1I1A     1*2     +4*4     =2+16=18
8A1B1C1D1E1F1G1H1I                        2*8            =16
                                           53    
n log2 n = 16*4=64
```

On the right I note the number of comparisons needed to merge the groups. To merge a set with x groups and a set with y groups, you need O(x y) comparisons, needed when the two sets are disjunct (i.e. compare each group of one set with each one of the other).
53 comparisons are needed in this example, which is below the n log2 n of 64. 
The comparisons on the left side behave very linear. If you analyze the pattern you get (for n>7)

```
Log2(n)-2+ Sum{i=0..Log2(n)}(2^i) = n/2 - 3 + Log2(n)
```

But wait, there is a square term at the right number of comparisons. Let's examine that. Each row (except the last merge) doubles the previous, and it ends with (n/4)^2 comparisons. This gives

```
Sum{i=0..Log2(n)-2}( (n/4)^2 (1/2)^i ) = 1/8 (n^2 - 2*n)
```

So, indeed, with this divide and conquer approach, our worst case number of comparisons is O(n^2), which seems logical. If all entries are different, and we only can test two for equality each time, we need to test each against each to find if there is really no pair.

Don't know if I miss something, but the problem seems for me to be not solvable in O(n log n) with divide and conquer when only comarisons are allowed.

Comment: Actually it is an algorithm question, so limited and restrict. I think you gave the proper solution in real-world project, Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

We can reduce your problem to following.

If the balls in the given set are grouped by colors, you wish to find if largest group is at least half the size of the set.

---

This is easier to solve recursively. (This problem is not defined for empty set, handle it separately.)

```
class Group { // with appropriate constructors
    int size;
    Color color;
}

Group findLargestGroupWithSameColors(Set<Ball> ballSet) {
    if (ballSet.size() > 1) {
        // Divide set into two (preferably equal) sets.
        Group first = recursive call on first half.
        Group second = recursive call on second half.
        if (first.color.equals(second.color)) {
            return new Group(first.color, first.size + second.size);
        } else {
            if (first.size > second.size) {
                return first;
            } else {
                return second;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return single element's color and size = 1
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: If you only ever return the largest group, I fear, that there are configurations, where you miss the largest group that may form by a subsequent merge of the smaller sets.

Comment: e.g. A B A B A C A C. On the 2 element sets (AB)(AB)(AC)(AC) your algorithm always returns the second element (2xB)(2xC), leaving out completely the As.

Comment: A little different from what I want... Thank you!